# Console App Reference in class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class console application named as Program.cs
I have an other project with a class library.
I want to use Program class of console application in class library project.
How can i add console application reference in dll class library.
Please help..

Comment: Instead of Generating as `Console application` for Program class why can't you create it as `dll` and give `reference` it to the class library

Comment: Although it might seem a rather weird thing, you can actually do it. Just add a project reference to the console app within your class library project. You'll have access to the `Program` class of the referenced assembly.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments and answers. I was just checking that is there any way to use console application classes in class library (dll) projects..

Comment: It's a reasonable question. It's *not* a duplicate as marked by varacarbas and @CodeCaster since, unlike the link, it's specific to Console apps. It may be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4771066), though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are (probably) doing it wrong.

Unless you have a *very* good reason for doing so, the Console application should reference the library, not the other way around. In general, 
stuff that is needed in more than one assembly should not be in a Console application. It should be in a class library project which is *referenced* from the Console application.

If you really need the whole *Program* class in the library, move it to the library and call it from the Console class. If you don't need the whole *Program* class, extract the parts you need into the library.

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with this approach; it works in VS2015 and it's been useful for me to test code that is a natural console app (like a command-line interpreter) in a test project, without having to deal with extra projects and longer build times.

Comment: @Steve _"There's nothing particularly wrong with this approach"_ - yeah there is, you're referencing an executable while you want shared code to reside in a library. See [Is it a bad practice to reference an exe file in C# project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835635/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-reference-an-exe-file-in-c-sharp-project) for a few reasons. Just that you _can_ do it, does not mean you _should_.

Comment: @SteveCooper: Point taken, there are some (rare) use cases, but chances are very high that this is not one of them (this is about a reference from a *class library* to a Console application). Usually, when people want to do this, it's a consequence from bad software architecture design, not a special case where it is legitimate.

Comment: @CodeCaster "you want shared code to reside in a library" -- if a console application can act as a library (and it can!) then why worry? E.g, if I write a command-line app (`clear-cache.exe`) and that contains `CacheCleanser.cs`, why introduce the third element of `CacheTools.csproj`?

Comment: @Steve because best practices exist for a reason. See the last two sentences of my previous comment.

Comment: @CodeCaster Your suggestion is a classic, familiar .Net pattern, but I'm not convinced it's objectively 'best practice.' 

Here are three modern uses of the pattern: 

1. Refactor a monolith to microservices. You extract a console app microservice, invoking it from your monolith during the refactor 
2. Migrate an app server to Azure; you create an Azure worker role, referencing a console app, invoking `Program.Main` on `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart`
3. You unit-test your command-line app from a test project. Maybe the OP isn't trying to do those, but I think all three are justified.

Comment: @Steve it is not "classic and familiar", it is essential. A console app, just as an ASP.NET site or WinForms/WPF application and so on, is the **UI layer** of a product. It should not contain **business logic**, for reasons like separation of concerns, testability and reusability. The only valid reason to add a reference to an executable project (console app, web app, desktop app, ...) is to unit test that project. In all other cases you should extract the business logic into a class library. Again, you _can_, but that does not mean you _should_ reference an executable project.

Comment: @Steve in all cases you mention apart from the unit testing, there is no use invoking the main in the sense of starting it as an application. If you're going to use it as a class library (i.e. invoke the business logic without wanting to start a new application), compile it as a class library.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't really see that. Console apps often function as public APIs, not UIs. Consider the C# compiler, invoked with filepaths and switches, via MSBUILD, via Visual Studio. VS is the UI; CSC.exe is the business layer. // Also, what's bugging me is this feels like an old worry, probably dating back to compilers that *do* differentiate libraries from exes; e.g., Visual C++ DLLs are different from Visual C++ EXE files. In .Net, all exes are already class libraries -- with an entry point. Given the extra code, complexity, and dependency management, strict separation doesn't always pay

Comment: @Steve I don't really think that is a valid comparison, because Visual Studio does not reference or link against `csc.exe` (if it even exports functions), it _invokes_ it through the command line. And now with Roslyn it's an entirely different story anyway. If your IPC mechanism is to start other executables with command line arguments, then still: that command line project can be a mere shell that parses command line arguments into library function arguments, and invokes the relevant functions in the shared class library. Again no reason to directly reference the console app.

Comment: @Steve not saying I would _never_ reference an executable, and I _do_ know how PEs, assemblies and entry points work, I'm just trying to argue that for _the average project_, unless you have compelling reasons not to, just move the **shared business logic** (that OP seems to be talking about) to its own class library for the benefits that offers, without having the drawbacks of that assembly being a command line executable. Nice discussion anyway. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster I would tend, in most cases, to do the same thing! I suppose I'm intrigued by the idea that there are now some compelling reasons to try it out -- Martin Fowler's idea of [Monolith First Microservices](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html) suggests slowly breaking off chunks of your app into separate executables. For .Net, that would look like a big codebase devolving into lots of executables. Could this be a mechanism? Anyway, thanks for the discussion!

Comment: @Steve for me, breaking up a monolith into microservices generally consists of a) extracting boundary models into their own library (DTOs), b) creating a standalone service (IIS/Windows Service) reachable through IPC (usually HTTP) and c) creating a client library exposing the service's API. Then consumers of said service can reference the model library and the client library, so they don't have to reference the service - they reference the client interface and talk to the hosted endpoint. This way the service can be a (GUI-less) executable without clients having to reference it.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments and answers. I was just checking that is there any way to use console application classes in class library (dll) projects..

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing a console app at the moment, and testing it through a VS2015 test project, which is exactly the situation I think you're describing. Just add it as a project reference.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing - I've got SpecFlow tests (class library project) driving a web browser using Selenium. An "out of process" activity needs a console app to run partway through a test. I'd like to run the output from the console project. Adding a project reference doesn't allow me to run the console app, but I guess this is done if I need access to the code _within_ the console app project. The run the app, am I correct in saying that I need to copy to a location somewhere in the code path  - which usually means placing it in the output folder for the class library project?

Answer (score 1):

@Muhammed, What makes a console app is just that the executor invokes the main method at runtime but the Console "app"/Project can be a project reference and all namespaces and classes referenced.

In Visual Studio Just right click on your **solution-> add Reference -> Click on Projects ->** Select the project if at all in the same solution.