# Could not load file or assembly C# Console Application with Class Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dependencies, azure-cognitive-services

I've created a `Class Library` in C# `.Net Framework 4.8`, and in the solution I've also included a `Console Application`, same target.
I'm running both in a `x64` configuration.
No errors on build.

I referenced the `App` in the `Library`, and when I run a `Button` in a `Form` in the `Class Library` I'm getting an error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'ExampleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'ExampleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'

I've combed the internet and SO for a solution. I tried repairing Visual Studio, I tried deleting the `.vs` folder in the projects, I tried things like:

[solution 1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/481)
and
[solution 2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/1451)

I seriously tried everything I could think of. It has to be something to do with the .dll dependencies imho, because the only one that my `ExampleApp` is using is the `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech` reference which I installed via NugetPackage in my solution.

No idea how to debug this further or get a proper trace stack from this error...

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you want the App in the Library and not the opposite?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by this sentence: "I referenced the App in the Library, and when I run a Button in a Form in the Class Library I'm getting an error".  What exactly is the button doing?  If you are trying to run the main method in a console app directly from within a Windows Forms app, I can see getting the kind of error you are describing.

Comment: You're referencing the app from the dll? And you have forms in your dll? That sounds strange/backwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console App Reference in class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087907/console-app-reference-in-class-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the .dll's **Copy Local** property to `True`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly @Yafim Simanovsky, I solved also my problem by changed `<Private>` flag to True.
[image]

My problem (“Could not load file or assembly…”) was with new Designer ‘WpfSurface.exe’ from VS 2022, which after changing the reference tags ‘Private’ to True, was able to copied all dependent .dll files to Cache.